# Localytics Android: Putting app in background causes BackgroundService to crash

Tags: android, background-service, localytics

Fatal Exception: com.localytics.android.LocalyticsManager$LocalyticsNotInitializedException: You must first initialize Localytics
       at com.localytics.android.LocalyticsManager.getLocationHandler(LocalyticsManager.java:1211)
       at com.localytics.android.LocalyticsManager.updateMonitoredGeofences(LocalyticsManager.java:1108)
       at com.localytics.android.BackgroundService.updateGeofences(BackgroundService.java:49)
       at com.localytics.android.BackgroundService.onRunTask(BackgroundService.java:30)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService$zzb.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: please add your try as well.